# How to make the Firefox application quit when the user hits its close button in Mac

Tags: macos, firefox

I open the Firefox application using a

```
     open -n -a Firefox.app
```

When I close the window of this Firefox application, only the window closes but the application still keeps running. I know that I could use Command+Q, but I want the application to quit when I click the Close button.

I have looked up for various command line options but haven't been able to figure out a way to start the Firefox application so that when I close the last window, the application itself quits.

I know this has more to do with Mac treating Applications and Windows differently. So how do I approach this problem?

Are there any other command line arguments that I can pass to make this work?

Comment: Re: https://github.com/Drive4ik/simple-tab-groups/issues/716#issuecomment-785504666 as far as I can tell, what's **required** is an enhancement to Firefox. When I have a Bugzilla@Mozilla reference, I'll add it to GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `osascript` to send a quit AppleEvent to the application using AppleScript

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "Firefox" to quit'
```

Comment: Paul but this needs to be done by command line right?              When the user clicks the close button its a Cmd-W, how can I make this behave as a Cmd-Q. Also the user may have Firefox running in other profiles so this way is a bit risky?

Comment: There can only be one instance of Firefox running for the current user - this isn't Windows - the user is probably not going to be happy about you quitting Firefox if they have other windows open anyway. You could enhance the above AppleScript though to check whether there are any other windows open before quitting.

Comment: There can easily be multiple instances of Firefox running for a given user on Mac; they just need to be using separate profiles.  I have 4 open right now, across 3 different Firefox versions...

Comment: @Boris: what do you mean by "profiles" ? Is this a Lion thing ?

Comment: @PaulR It's a Firefox thing.  See http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Profiles for some basic info.  You can script Firefox to open with a particular profile pretty easily: `Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -profile /path/to/profile`.

Comment: @Boris: how does that translate to multiple instances of the *application* though ? Does Firefox really launch a new instance of the Firefox app for each profile ? Do you see multiple Firefox icons in the application switcher and the dock ? How is the ambiguity resolved when you e.g. send an AppleEvent ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes, that launches multiple instances of the application.  There are multiple icons in the task switcher and in the dock, and multiple entries in `ps` and in Activity Monitor.  I have no idea what happens when you try to send an AppleEvent.

Comment: @Boris: OK - thanks - I would argue that's pretty much a non-standard and unsupported way of running apps under Mac OS X.

Comment: @PaulR It's a completely fine way of running apps, depending on the goal.  Lots of apps support being run this way.  And of course if one wants to stick to the double-click method one can always make a copy of the app bundle (so it looks like two different apps now) and change the default command-line arguments for it to point to a particular profile.  For that matter, you can simply have app bundles for different Firefox versions and set them to use different profiles, then run them normally.  What you're really seeing is that AppleEvents aren't quite compatible with the unix underneath OS X.